# why some api platform results show iri and other not?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

i have an order entity which displays a company and paymentStates. Now im confused. When i fetch an order the company is displayed as object and the paymentStates as iri.

example response:

```
"company": {
    "@id": "/api/companies/d3b832a9-35e3-4f50-bba6-98bb2646e161",
    "@type": "Company",
    "id": "d3b83xyz-35e3-4f50-0815-98bb2646e161",
    "name": "Blubb",
    "businessType": "company",
    "email": "myVeryNiceEmail@gmail.com"
},
"paymentStates": [
    "/api/payment_states/10",
    "/api/payment_states/11",
    "/api/payment_states/12"
]
//....
```

I have no idea why at this point i get only the iri. The api platform declaration of both files as following:

```
//Company
#[ApiResource(
  normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
  denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
  collectionOperations: ["get"]
)]
class Company
{
  #[Groups(["read"])]
  private $name;
}

//paymentState
#[ApiResource(
  normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
  denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']]
)]
class PaymentState
{
    #[Groups(["read", "write"])]
    private $created;
}
```

Where is the different and how i can decide to what to show, because sometimes i need an iri but i get an arry or object.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and it was a very stupid mistake.

The class `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;` wasn't imported and the php8 annotation `#[Groups(["read"])]` wasn't called.

The strangest thing at this point is, that symfony dont throw an exception, thatswhy u have to look closely if this class was really imported.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `#[Groups(["read"])]` attribute, on `paymentState` property in the `Company` class?

Comment: yes i have, but i have found the mistake